# How to Remove Trailing Comma From Meta Keyword

Tags: php, wordpress, keyword, meta, genesis

I would like to remove the trailing comma from the meta keywords tag from this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="enhancing,nutritional,supplements," />
```

To this:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="enhancing,nutritional,supplements" />
```

Here is the full code.

/*
Automatically generates a post/page meta keywords
for SEO in Genesis framework.
If Genesis doesn't return a keywords then the keywords are
automatically generated from the post-tags or
else from the post/page title.
*/

```
add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'my_auto_keywords' , 11 );
function my_auto_keywords(){
if(
!is_singular() ||
genesis_get_custom_field( '_genesis_keywords' ) ||
genesis_get_custom_field( '_aioseop_keywords' ) ||
genesis_get_custom_field( 'thesis_keywords' ) ||
genesis_get_custom_field( 'keywords' )
) return;

$tags = get_the_tags(); #wp

if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $keywords .= $tag->name . ', ';
    }
}

if ($keywords) {
    $keywords = '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $keywords . '" />';  
}
else {
    $title = get_the_title();
    $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $title);
    $keywords = array_map('strtolower', $keywords);
    $keywords = array_diff($keywords, my_excluded_words()); //remove useless words
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
        $kw_list .= $keyword . ',';
    $keywords = '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $kw_list . '" />';   
}

echo $keywords . "\r\n";
}

function my_excluded_words(){
return array ("testword", "testword2", "testword3", "testword4");
}
```

Comment: `$kw_list = rtrim($kw_list, ',');`

Comment: Hi Mark, this line of code removes everything (keywords, commas and trailing comma).

Comment: If that line removes the keywords as well, then you are running a seriously flawed version of PHP

Answer (score -1):

Replace this:

```
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $keywords .= $tag->name . ', ';
    }
}
```

With this:

```
if ($tags) {
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $keywords[] = $tag->name;
    }
    $keywords = implode(',', $keywords);
}
```

and replace this:

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    $kw_list .= $keyword . ',';
```

with this:

```
$kw_list = implode(',', $keywords);
```

Comment: @Donovan oops, sorry, I didn't see the second keywords list... fixing.

Comment: @Donovan ok fixed, now try it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
$keywords = join(",", array_map(function($tag){ return $tag->name; }, $tags ));
if($keywords) {
  $keywords = '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $keywords . '" />';
}
```

Comment: Hey shooper, I got an error with our code. I probably put at the wrong location.